# Is possible to have for with two paths

Tags: batch-file, cmd

With this code:

```
Rem If "%~1"=="" Exit/B

For %%A In ("%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Outlook\*.ost"a) Do (

    Rem "%~1" "%~f0" :: "%%~fA"


    If %%~zA Lss %maxbytesize% (

    ) Else If "%email%"=="0" (

        msg * algo

    )
)
```

Is possible to make the for  search two different path, like:

```
For %%A In ("%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Outlook\*.ost" and C:\Users\%username%\Documents\Outlook Files\) Do (
```

Comment: Instead of continuing to create new user names on this site and posting effectively bad interpretations of the same piece of code, try telling us exactly what your goal/intention is and helpers could possibly work through a solution with you all in one question.

Answer (score 1):

Almost how you've done it!

```bat
For %%A In ("%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Outlook\*.ost" "%UserProfile%\Documents\Outlook Files\*.pst") Do (
```

You can split them onto separate lines to make it easier to read too:

```bat
For %%A In (
    "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Outlook\*.ost"
    "%UserProfile%\Documents\Outlook Files\*.pst"
    "%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\*.pst"
) Do (
```